# Is this standard deviation calculation correct?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

I got an answer of 11.88 but apparently the correct answer is 547. Which part of this solution is wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine to me. I also got 11.88.

The standard deviation cannot be 547 as the mean plus/minus one standard deviation should include 68% of all results.

Double check you are looking at the right answer in your book.

Comment: The answer was given to us by our teacher in class. She gave wrong answer.